# How to retrieve multiple entries from table into one list?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hql

thanks for helping ;)

I'm new to hibernate and wanna try it for my private project.
What i want to do is: I want to have a class like

```
public class Playlist {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private long owner_ID;
    private ArrayList<String> urls;
}
```

Where the list should contain urls to some songs.

At the moment I have one entry in my db for each url. **Is there a better way to do that?**
And to my main question: **How can I recieve/save the list?**

I can get a "normal" table entry rn but I haven't worked with Hibernate and Lists/ArrayLists in combination jet.

Hope you can help me ;)

If additional information is required feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `urls` is a basic value (`String`) you can use `@ElementCollection`.

```
@Entity
public class Playlist {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private long owner_ID;
    
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> urls;
}
```

This mapping links two tables:

- `playlist` table which has `id`, `name`, `owner_ID` columns
- `playlist_urls` table which has `playlist_id` and `urls` columns.

For more information take a look at [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection).

Comment: Oh wait no...It tells me `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: java.util.ArrayList collection type not supported for property: de.dragonbot.entity.Playlist.urls`.

Comment: You should change `private ArrayList<String> urls;` to `private List<String> urls;`